# Spring Tool Suit is getting crashed after few minutes of running

Tags: java-8, spring-tool-suite, jvm-crash

My specifications are :Java version : 1.8.0_121,Windows 7, 64 bit OS,STS version : 3.8.3

I have already tried all possible options available on similar questions like :

1. Increase heapsizr in STS.ini file
2. Add VM argument to exclude compiler issues
3. Set parameter for Dashboard as false
4. Different JDK version

It's a new machine and it seems that it might be a machine infrastructure/drivers related issues. Can someone help me please to resolve the issue as I am stuck here at this issue for 10 days now.

Here are the error logs :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000063f91576, pid=2292, tid=0x0000000000001aa8
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x4a1576]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000017176000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6824, stack(0x0000000018730000,0x0000000018830000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000012

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000017176000, RBX=0x000000001882edb0, RCX=0x000000000000000b, RDX=0x0000000000000263
RSP=0x000000001882c370, RBP=0x0000000000010b50, RSI=0x00000000204385b0, RDI=0x0000000000000263
R8 =0x0000000000000012, R9 =0x000000006430be10, R10=0x000000001882c710, R11=0x000000001882c400
R12=0x0000000020540050, R13=0x000000001882ca00, R14=0x0000000063af0000, R15=0x000000006430be10
RIP=0x0000000063f91576, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000017176000 is a thread
RBX=0x000000001882edb0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017176000
RCX=0x000000000000000b is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000263 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001882c370 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017176000
RBP=0x0000000000010b50 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000204385b0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000263 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000006430be10 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000001882c710 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017176000
R11=0x000000001882c400 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017176000
R12=0x0000000020540050 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000001882ca00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017176000
R14=0x0000000063af0000 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000006430be10 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000018730000,0x0000000018830000],  sp=0x000000001882c370,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x4a1576]
V  [jvm.dll+0x49d10a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x49e5d8]
V  [jvm.dll+0x468a3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x473f5b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x476867]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4591e2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa5ca2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa65df]
V  [jvm.dll+0x244e1f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x29c69a]
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21db7]
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21e53]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1652d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2c521]


Current CompileTask:
C2:  16551 3377       4       org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl::getEAllStructuralFeatures (220 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000199c8000 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5676, stack(0x000000001f700000,0x000000001f800000)]
  0x00000000199c2000 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2848, stack(0x000000001c250000,0x000000001c350000)]
  0x00000000199c6800 JavaThread "EMF Reference Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2544, stack(0x000000001c510000,0x000000001c610000)]
  0x00000000199c5800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=4676, stack(0x000000001c620000,0x000000001c720000)]
  0x00000000199c5000 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6632, stack(0x000000001c350000,0x000000001c450000)]
  0x00000000199c3800 JavaThread "Start Level: Equinox Container: c6c9f5ff-dcb1-4a35-9b8e-e71e806a34d3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6376, stack(0x000000001bf50000,0x000000001c050000)]
  0x00000000199c2800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher@77db3d02" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1540, stack(0x000000001be50000,0x000000001bf50000)]
  0x0000000019dca000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7144, stack(0x000000001ad80000,0x000000001ae80000)]
  0x0000000019d49800 JavaThread "Active Thread: Equinox Container: c6c9f5ff-dcb1-4a35-9b8e-e71e806a34d3" [_thread_blocked, id=7148, stack(0x000000001ac80000,0x000000001ad80000)]
  0x00000000189be800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7056, stack(0x0000000018e30000,0x0000000018f30000)]
  0x000000001717f000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6828, stack(0x0000000018d30000,0x0000000018e30000)]
  0x000000001717d000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6820, stack(0x0000000018830000,0x0000000018930000)]
=>0x0000000017176000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6824, stack(0x0000000018730000,0x0000000018830000)]
  0x0000000017173000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6704, stack(0x0000000018630000,0x0000000018730000)]
  0x0000000017170000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3728, stack(0x0000000018530000,0x0000000018630000)]
  0x0000000017158800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6636, stack(0x0000000018370000,0x0000000018470000)]
  0x0000000017111800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5552, stack(0x0000000018270000,0x0000000018370000)]
  0x00000000022ae000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3320, stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000017109800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000018170000,0x0000000018270000] [id=6132]
  0x00000000189c9000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000018f30000,0x0000000019030000] [id=7152]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000022ac490] CompiledIC_lock - owner thread: 0x000000001717f000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 39578K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000dea80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 60% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d7c26ad8,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000da000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000de000000,0x00000000de000000,0x00000000dea80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 33668K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 19% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000820e1318,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 27426K, capacity 30166K, committed 30464K, reserved 1075200K
  class space    used 3217K, capacity 3969K, committed 4096K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000118c0000,0x0000000011cd0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000114c0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006430b6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012380000, 0x0000000014380000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014380000, 0x0000000016380000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000610000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=11867Kb max_used=11922Kb free=233892Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002500000, 0x00000000030b0000, 0x0000000011500000]
 total_blobs=3840 nmethods=3195 adapters=556
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 16.299 Thread 0x000000001717f000 3582       2       jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Label::<init> (5 bytes)
Event: 16.300 Thread 0x000000001717f000 nmethod 3582 0x00000000030a8f90 code [0x00000000030a90e0, 0x00000000030a9230]
Event: 16.300 Thread 0x000000001717f000 3581       2       jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Item::<init> (5 bytes)
Event: 16.300 Thread 0x000000001717f000 nmethod 3581 0x00000000030a92d0 code [0x00000000030a9420, 0x00000000030a9570]
Event: 16.420 Thread 0x000000001717f000 3583   !   2       org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager::findClassImpl (396 bytes)
Event: 16.426 Thread 0x000000001717f000 nmethod 3583 0x00000000030a9e50 code [0x00000000030aa340, 0x00000000030abb88]
Event: 16.459 Thread 0x000000001717f000 3584       2       org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter::preFindLocalClass (153 bytes)
Event: 16.461 Thread 0x000000001717f000 nmethod 3584 0x00000000030adad0 code [0x00000000030adcc0, 0x00000000030ae348]
Event: 16.511 Thread 0x000000001717f000 3585       2       java.util.AbstractList::equals (117 bytes)
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 nmethod 3585 0x00000000026c6dd0 code [0x00000000026c6fc0, 0x00000000026c7428]

GC Heap History (8 events):
Event: 3.830 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 65536K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000daa80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000da000000,0x00000000da000000,0x00000000daa80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000da000000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000080000000,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 7916K, capacity 8078K, committed 8320K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 829K, capacity 858K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 3.868 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 10739K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000daa80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9ffcee8,0x00000000da000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000da000000,0x00000000da000000,0x00000000daa80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 12063K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 6% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000080bc7de0,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 7916K, capacity 8078K, committed 8320K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 829K, capacity 858K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 6.924 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 76275K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000daa80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9ffcee8,0x00000000da000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000da000000,0x00000000da000000,0x00000000daa80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 12063K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 6% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000080bc7de0,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 12064K, capacity 13124K, committed 13312K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1251K, capacity 1491K, committed 1536K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 6.975 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 10731K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000dea80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x00000000da000000,0x00000000daa7adc8,0x00000000daa80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000da000000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 26004K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 14% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000081965290,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 12064K, capacity 13124K, committed 13312K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1251K, capacity 1491K, committed 1536K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 10.331 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 40025K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000dea80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 44% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d721b788,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x00000000da000000,0x00000000daa7adc8,0x00000000daa80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000da000000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 26004K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 14% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000081965290,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 19076K, capacity 21152K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2001K, capacity 2653K, committed 2688K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 10.440 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 10747K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000dea80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9ffedd8,0x00000000da000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000de000000,0x00000000de000000,0x00000000dea80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 33034K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 18% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000082042a18,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 19076K, capacity 21152K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2001K, capacity 2653K, committed 2688K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 10.440 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 10747K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000dea80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9ffedd8,0x00000000da000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000de000000,0x00000000de000000,0x00000000dea80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 33034K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 18% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000082042a18,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 19076K, capacity 21152K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2001K, capacity 2653K, committed 2688K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 10.791 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 0K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000dea80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d9580000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000d9580000,0x00000000da000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000de000000,0x00000000de000000,0x00000000dea80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 33668K [0x0000000080000000, 0x000000008ab00000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 175104K, 19% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000820e1318,0x000000008ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 19076K, capacity 21152K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2001K, capacity 2653K, committed 2688K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 15.680 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002f2d784 method=java.lang.reflect.Method.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 49
Event: 15.812 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002d571a8 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 440
Event: 15.812 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002c9808c method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 440
Event: 15.838 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000027b9790 method=java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; @ 1
Event: 15.838 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000267b10c method=java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; @ 1
Event: 15.916 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002979cc8 method=java.util.HashMap.getNode(ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/HashMap$Node; @ 62
Event: 16.105 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002df2fec method=org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.MinimalEObjectImpl.fieldIndex(I)I @ 47
Event: 16.105 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003035f38 method=org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EContentsEList$FeatureIteratorImpl.hasNext()Z @ 300
Event: 16.139 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003032770 method=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.commands.impl.CommandImpl.eIsSet(I)Z @ 136
Event: 16.365 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002d1c3b0 method=org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotificationRequired()Z @ 8

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 14.291 Thread 0x00000000199c7000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TriggeringPolicyBaseCustomizer> (0x00000000d6c71d38) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, 
Event: 14.293 Thread 0x00000000199c7000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicyCustomizer> (0x00000000d6c7bad8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.
Event: 14.332 Thread 0x00000000199c7000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/eclipse/m2e/logback/appender/EclipseLogAppenderBeanInfo> (0x00000000d6ca0110) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp,
Event: 14.333 Thread 0x00000000199c7000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/eclipse/m2e/logback/appender/EclipseLogAppenderCustomizer> (0x00000000d6dc68e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cp
Event: 15.349 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Exception <a 'java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException'> (0x00000000d72b1120) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\reflection.cpp, line 1092]
Event: 15.410 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002ec106a to 0x0000000002ec13d5
Event: 15.838 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000027b93d4 to 0x00000000027b9779
Event: 15.838 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000267ad59 to 0x000000000267b0f5
Event: 16.085 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000d787bfd0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 16.105 Thread 0x00000000022ae000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000003035a96 to 0x0000000003035f21

Events (10 events):
Event: 16.461 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026c2310
Event: 16.461 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026c6a90
Event: 16.511 loading class java/util/Collections$EmptyListIterator
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026c8390
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026cc410
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026dd710
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026e06d0
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026fcd90
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000026fdfd0
Event: 16.512 Thread 0x000000001717f000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002703190


Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000044f000     C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\STS.exe
0x0000000077690000 - 0x0000000077839000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077570000 - 0x000000007768f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd8a0000 - 0x000007fefd90b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000077470000 - 0x000000007756a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefee90000 - 0x000007fefeef7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe000000 - 0x000007fefe00e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff8d0000 - 0x000007feff999000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefde30000 - 0x000007fefdecf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefbfa0000 - 0x000007fefc194000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefd9d0000 - 0x000007fefda41000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feff1c0000 - 0x000007feff1ee000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefda50000 - 0x000007fefdb59000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000     C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740\eclipse_1617.dll
0x000007feff1f0000 - 0x000007feff2cb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefdc00000 - 0x000007fefdc1f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefdd00000 - 0x000007fefde2d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000007fefc740000 - 0x000007fefc74c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000063af0000 - 0x000000006438b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef8460000 - 0x000007fef8469000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefeda0000 - 0x000007fefeded000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007feff2d0000 - 0x000007feff2d8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefba60000 - 0x000007fefba9b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077850000 - 0x0000000077857000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000737c0000 - 0x0000000073891000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
0x0000000067610000 - 0x000000006761f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000066a80000 - 0x0000000066aa9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.dll
0x0000000066a60000 - 0x0000000066a76000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe010000 - 0x000007fefed98000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff460000 - 0x000007feff663000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd5e0000 - 0x000007fefd5ef000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefceb0000 - 0x000007fefcec7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcb70000 - 0x000007fefcbb7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefc930000 - 0x000007fefc94e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd510000 - 0x000007fefd51f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000066720000 - 0x000000006673a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefce10000 - 0x000007fefce65000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefce00000 - 0x000007fefce07000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefa8f0000 - 0x000007fefa917000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa930000 - 0x000007fefa93b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefa630000 - 0x000007fefa648000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fefa610000 - 0x000007fefa621000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x0000000066700000 - 0x0000000066711000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefbd50000 - 0x000007fefbda6000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007fefdb60000 - 0x000007fefdbf9000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fefdc20000 - 0x000007fefdcf7000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000000001cc30000 - 0x000000001ccd7000     C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\640\0\.cp\swt-win32-4628.dll
0x000007fefedf0000 - 0x000007fefee87000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x000007fef9650000 - 0x000007fef96c1000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fefded0000 - 0x000007fefdffa000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x000007feff2e0000 - 0x000007feff458000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x000007fefd690000 - 0x000007fefd7f7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefd680000 - 0x000007fefd68f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007feff670000 - 0x000007feff8c9000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x000007fefb8a0000 - 0x000007fefb8b8000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefbe20000 - 0x000007fefbf4c000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x0000000002340000 - 0x000000000235e000     C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\640\0\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-4628.dll
0x000007fefbb30000 - 0x000007fefbd45000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_2b24536c71ed437a\gdiplus.dll
0x000007fefb700000 - 0x000007fefb82a000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180012000     C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\137\0\.cp\os\win32\x86_64\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x000007fefae60000 - 0x000007fefae75000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007feef110000 - 0x000007feef125000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007feef080000 - 0x000007feef099000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefcc90000 - 0x000007fefcceb000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007feef0c0000 - 0x000007feef0cb000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007feef0b0000 - 0x000007feef0c0000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x000007fefc810000 - 0x000007fefc817000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fef72e0000 - 0x000007fef72e8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa7b0000 - 0x000007fefa803000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fef04c0000 - 0x000007fef05e5000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Xms256m -Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10 -Xverify:none -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 -Xmx2048m 
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Dinesh\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Dinesh\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE;
USERNAME=AcnTUSR
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.17514)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 6169616k(4222592k free), swap 12337376k(9491452k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sun Feb 05 21:00:47 2017
elapsed time: 16 seconds (0d 0h 0m 16s)
```

Comment: looks like the internal hotspot compiler crashes the JVM. Did you report this to the JDK bug database? Looks like something they should fix.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be a machine related issue, it is purely java related issue, C2 compiler having crash during method compilation of  one of the eclipse generated methods org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl::getEAllStructuralFeatures

Current CompileTask:
C2:  16551 3377       4       org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl::getEAllStructuralFeatures (220 bytes)

It will be difficult to us (Oracle Java Team) to debug and fix the issue without having proper reproducer. As a workaround you can try to exclude the method from compilation using below vm flag
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,
Find more details about the usage of vm flag here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using a previous version of the JRE, specifically 1.8.0u40 worked for me when I got a similar error.

I've been trying to track down a similar frequently appearing core dump in our software (possibly also like JDK-8176028 and JDK-8176347). In my case, the failing compile task is always pointing to the same function from an old library that we just started to recompile from source. We were able to work around it by using our previously compiled version that was compiled with the same source but with a JDK of 1.6.

I tried to create the crash by just running the function without any of the other components (Tomcat 8.0.42 and the webapp that runs it), but it doesn't crash. I don't know how to make it repeatable without the full system.

Compiling with 1.8.0u40 also caused the crash when run on 1.8.0u121. 
However, compiling with 1.8.0u121 and using the 1.8.0u40 JRE does not crash.

Comparing the decompiled code of the affected class results in identical code other than optimization differences:

```
//1.8 compiler
for (int k=0; k<3; k++) {
   ...
   if (k==0) {
      var = var2*var3;
      continue;
   }
   if (k==1) var = var4*var3;
}

//1.6 compiler
for (int k=0; k<3; k++) {
   ...
   if (k==0)
      var = var2*var3;
   else if (k==1) var = var4*var3;
}
```

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000074c54cb0, pid=1596, tid=0x0000000000000670

...

Current thread (0x0000000015568800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1648, stack(0x0000000016ce0000,0x0000000016de0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000000000002c

...

Current CompileTask:
C2:53351360 39325       4       com.proprietary.package::staticFunctionName (215 bytes)